Flutter 2.8.0 iOS Build Fails with CocoaPods Invalid Lockfile Error, Works Fine on Android
I'm encountering a specific issue while running pod install on a Flutter 2.8.0 project for iOS. This problem does not occur on the Android version of the same project. Below is the detailed error message I receive:
Error:
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Finding Podfile changes
      - GoogleMaps

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_a_d_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/a/d/d/GoogleMaps/9.0.0/GoogleMaps.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/a/d/d/GoogleMaps/8.4.0/GoogleMaps.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/a/d/d/GoogleMaps/8.4.0/GoogleMaps.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/a/d/d/GoogleMaps/8.4.0/GoogleMaps.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update

    Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
    [!] Invalid Lockfile in `/Users/riccardo/Desktop/Progetti/Personali/quoteflutter/ios/Pods/Manifest.lock`

    /Users/riccardo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods-core/lockfile.rb:42:in `from_file'

pubscec.yamk
name: quote
description: quote

version: 3.2.0+20

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.11.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  custom_switch: ^0.0.1
  settings_ui: ^0.4.0
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.0
  simple_permissions: any
  location: ^2.5.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.0
  percent_indicator: ^2.1.3
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3
  barcode_scan2: 4.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^1.0.0
  json_annotation: ^3.0.1
  pdf: ^3.4.1
  data_tables: ^1.0.3
  network_image_to_byte: ^0.0.1
  date_picker_timeline: ^1.2.0
  image: ^3.0.1
  line_icons: any
  printing: ^5.7.4
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.3.8
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.0.0
  back_button_interceptor: ^4.2.4
  google_maps_flutter: any
  provider: ^4.1.3
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.0
  image_picker: any
  image_cropper: ^1.2.0
  flutter_picker: any
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  file_picker: ^4.3.0
  cross_file: ^0.3.2
  cron: ^0.4.0
  line_awesome_flutter: ^1.0.1
  flutter_screenutil: ^1.0.2
  _fe_analyzer_shared: ^34.0.0
  theme_provider: ^0.5.0
  timer_builder: ^2.0.0
  ionicons: any
  dropdown_button2: ^1.0.0
  flutter_custom_tabs: "^0.6.0"
  url_launcher: ^5.4.0
  camera: any
  qr_code_scanner: "^0.4.0"
  flutter_pdfview: "1.0.4"

dev_dependencies:
  dart_code_metrics: ^4.8.1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.0.1

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/img/icona.png"
  android: true
  ios: true

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/images/avatar.png
    - assets/images/addicon.png
    - assets/images/logo.png


  fonts:
    - family: WorkSansSemiBold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Work_Sans/WorkSans-SemiBold.ttf
    - family: WorkSansBold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Work_Sans/WorkSans-Bold.ttf
    - family: WorkSansMedium
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Work_Sans/WorkSans-Medium.ttf


There might be an issue with the Podfile.lock file in your project. Maybe a mismatch between the versions of the dependencies listed in the lockfile and those specified in the Podfile.
Try to do the following :

flutter clean. (Podfile.lock will be deleted, if not delete it manually)
pod install. try this command in the terminal of the project.
This might fix your issue.

